# $wp_customize->remove_section for customizer setting?

Tags: customization, themes, admin-menu

I use an [underscores](http://underscores.me/) theme and try to remove the nav menu without any result :

```
  $wp_customize->remove_section('colors'); // works
  $wp_customize->remove_section('background_image'); // ok
  $wp_customize->remove_section('header_image'); // ok
  $wp_customize->remove_section('static_front_page'); // ok
  $wp_customize->remove_panel('widgets'); // ok
  $wp_customize->remove_panel('menu_navs'); // not ok
  $wp_customize->remove_section('menu_navs'); // not ok
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Is that all your code? Are you using it in some action hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to remove the default `nav_menus` panel, you have the id wrong.  Also, you'll need to add a priority of at least 20 to the `customize_register` hook, assuming you're using that hook.

```
function remove_customizer_settings( $wp_customize ){

  $wp_customize->remove_panel('nav_menus');

}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_customizer_settings', 20 );
```

Comment: « Also, you'll need to add a priority of at least 20 », OK I was focused on  $wp_customize->remove_panel('nav_menus'); I had `add_action( 'customize_register', 'remove_customizer_settings');`

Comment: `Notice: WP_Customize_Manager::remove_panel was called incorrectly` when used in the theme, but it does work if wp_debug is set to false.